# Migrate Non RAID 2008 Single Drive Server to SSD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, clone

I have a customer running a custom app that would benefit from improved SSD speed. Their existing server is running Windows 2008 with a single SATA drive (no RAID). The server has an open drive bay and I have a 2.5" SSD that I'm about to install in it.

What is the path of least resistance in migrating the entire existing drive (broken into multiple partitions) to the SSD and have the system be bootable from the SSD. I would like to not reinstall anything if possible.

I have a bunch of experience using Clonezilla, but not for Windows.

P.S. the new drive is approximately the same size as the old (500 GB)
P.S.S. it's a Dell R320 Server that's part of an Enterprise network

Comment: Y U no use RAID?  U hate UR client data?

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla Live will do the trick, but you will need to make sure that the destination drive is at least as big or bigger than the source drive and you will need to copy the MBR as well - there is an option for this when you setup the cloning.

Plug both disks in, boot from the Clonezilla USB drive and then perform a disk-to-disk clone.
After the cloning is complete, unplug the mechanical drive and boot from the SSD.

Make sure you select the appropriate source and destination disks and backup your source disk before you attempt cloning!

If your source disk is larger than your destination, the process is a little bit more complicated. It involves shrinking your existing partitions until all of them would fit on your SSD, then you would need to run Clonezilla Live partition to partition.